# Como passar parâmetros usando o redirect do cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-2

Eu estou usando o seguinte trecho de código na minha controller:

```
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'duplicate', $contact));
```

A variável $contact contém um array.

O comando redireciona para a função `duplicate`, mas não passa os dados como parâmetro. Segundo a documentação do cakePHP deveria funcionar.

Como corrigir este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que o seu *array* `$contact` seja algo assim:

```
array(
    'nome' => 'Fulano',
    'email' => 'fulano@abc.com'
);
```

Você teria duas formas que receber estes valores na sua *action*. A primeira é passando cada um destes pares de *chave-valor* como próprio parâmetro no *array* do método [`redirect`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::redirect):

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'action' => 'duplicate',
    'nome' => 'Fulano',
    'email' => 'fulano@abc.com')
);
```

Todos os valores subsequentes à *action* será um parâmetro do seu método, que você receberá assim:

```
// URL: controller/duplicate/nome:Fulano/email:fulano@abc.com
public function duplicate($nome, $email) {
}
```

Ou como *query string*, você pode passar todo o *array*:

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'action' => 'duplicate',
    '?' => $contact)
);
```

Vai ficar assim o seu método:

```
// URL: controller/duplicate?nome=Fulano&email=fulano@abc.com
public function duplicate() {
    echo $this->request->params['nome'];
    echo $this->request->params['email'];
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, fiz da primeira forma e deu certinho aqui.